# Can't create Host-only network on Virtual box 6.1.44 with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

When trying to create a host-only network on VirtualBox I get the same error listed in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291009/host-only-network-with-virtual-box-and-windows-host-machine-cannot-find-device), and the listed solution is to use VirtualBox 5.0.14, but this is incompatible with Ubuntu 22.04. There doesn't seem to be any other solution or description of why it happens that I can find.

I get this error when attempting to create a host-only network using VirtualBox version 6.1.44 on Ubuntu release 22.04:

```
VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl failed for /dev/vboxnetctl: Inappropriate ioctl for devic.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: HostNetworkInterfaceWrap
Interface: IHostNetworkInterface {455f8c45-44a0-a470-ba20-27890b96dba9}
```

This is not due to inconsistent dependencies from using different VirtualBox versions as I re-flashed Ubuntu 22.04 fresh and only installed VirtualBox version 6.1.44 and the error persists.

Comment: You are running quite an old version of Virtual box. The latest release is version 7.0. 5 was released April 28th 2017

Comment: Title says version 7 question says version 5 please correct.

Comment: @David I referenced version 5.0.14 because the solution in the post I linked was to use 5.0.14. I was simply stating why a solution to seemingly the same problem did not work. I was running 7.0.8 as it is the most recent stable version and I get this error.

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for letting me know the compatible VirtualBox version for my release, but I am still getting the same error message on VirtualBox version 6.1.44.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: If you add incompatible software to your system, it can mess up dependencies for other software. So suddenly installing the supported version won't necessarily solve the problem if you messed up dependencies by installing an unsupported version.

Comment: @Nmath I reflashed Ubuntu 22.04 and started out with the correct VirtualBox 6.1.44 and the error persists.

Comment: @karel Yes thank you so much!